# How to get address of function generated by MACRO inside OPENSSL

Tags: c, linux, macros

I am trying to find address of two functions defined inside openssl. One defined as  normal function and another defined
as MACRO function.

**Here is details of two functions :**

Inside bn_mul.c file,

```
    #ifdef BN_RECURSION 
                         //macro function
        void bn_mul_recursive(BN_ULONG *r, BN_ULONG *a, BN_ULONG *b, int n2,
        int dna, int dnb, BN_ULONG *t)
    #endif // BN_RECURSION 

       //normal function
int BN_mul(BIGNUM *r, const BIGNUM *a, const BIGNUM *b, BN_CTX *ctx)
{

}
```

Inside bn.h header file,

```
#define BN_RECURSION 

int BN_mul(BIGNUM *r, const BIGNUM *a, const BIGNUM *b, BN_CTX *ctx);
```

When I try to find address of BN_mul function and bn_mul_recursive MACRO function , I am trying to use &BN_mul and &bn_mul_recursive respectively.
**I am getting error for bn_mul_recursive MACRO function.**
I have used -fPIC while building openssl. I used Following command to compile,

gcc address_macro2.c -lcrypto

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <openssl/bn.h>

int main()
{
printf("Address of BN_mul =%p\n",&BN_mul);
printf("Address of bn_mul_recursive=%p\n",&bn_mul_recursive);
return 0;
}

Error:
address_macro2.c:13:44: error: ‘bn_mul_recursive’ undeclared (first use in this function)
```

I am using gcc under linux. How to resolve that error ?

I can't use -I/path_to_file_bn_mul.c as this will nullified effect of -fPIC option.

Any clue or link will be a great help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should probably read up on what macros are/how they work.

Comment: @Qix, I read them, but unable to understand in shared library with PIC scenario. I resolve the above error, with -I/Path_to_file_contain_definition option, but I want to resolve it without -I option.

Comment: Again, read up on what macros are. You're misunderstanding how they work. They don't, won't, and will never have addresses.

Comment: @Qix, so you are saying void bn_mul_recursive() function will not have any address , just like normal function BN_mul in this case ? I know macro is replaced by preprocessor, but in this case it is function defined as MACRO. So how this macro function call will be replaced before runtime as this macro function may be called multiple times?

Comment: @Qix, may be I am not using correct keyword for above function void bn_mul_recursive, which is defined in MACRO style. you may correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: If you have `BN_RECURSION` defined, then yes. It's unclear where your files are/what is including what.

Comment: Inside bn.h header file, #define BN_RECURSION is there. Inside bn_mul.c file, #ifdef BN_RECURSION 
void bn_mul_recursive(BN_ULONG *r, BN_ULONG *a, BN_ULONG *b, int n2,
 int dna, int dnb, BN_ULONG *t)
#endif // BN_RECURSION is there . both files are inside openssl folder and I have build shared library using -fPIC option

Answer (score 0):

Finally , I resolved the above problem.

The error shows, program is unable to find the definition of bn_mul_recursive function in the scope of address_macro2.c program.

So I add following statement

```
 extern  void bn_mul_recursive(BN_ULONG *, BN_ULONG *, BN_ULONG *, int ,    int , int , BN_ULONG *);
```

Now my correct program is,

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <openssl/bn.h>

extern  void bn_mul_recursive(BN_ULONG *, BN_ULONG *, BN_ULONG *, int , int , int , BN_ULONG *);

int main()
{
printf("Address of BN_mul =%p\n",&BN_mul);
printf("Address of bn_mul_recursive=%p\n",&bn_mul_recursive);
return 0;
}
```

Output :

```
Address of BN_mul =0x8048430
Address of bn_mul_recursive=0x8048460
```